# cpp inheritance questions

Tags: c++, virtual, virtual-functions

What other reason apart from inheritance should a class need to have its functions as virtual?

What happens during run time where a base class is inherited and the derived class doesn't implement few of the base class function and a third class calls that undefined methods which are defined as virtual in base. seg fault or will it call the base class function?

What should I do if I don't want to define all the functions in my base class on my derived class but still have the necessary inheritance in place?

Answer (score 3):

> What other reason apart from inheritance should a class need to have
>   its functions as virtual?

There is no reasonable usage for having a `virtual` function, if you are not dealing with inheritance. Both are meant for each other.

> What happens during run time where a base class is inherited and the
>   derived class doesn't implement few of the base class function and a
>   third class calls that undefined methods which are defined as virtual
>   in base. seg fault or will it call the base class function?

If Derived class don't make any declaration about the `virtual` function at all in its body, then (immediate) base class `virtual` functions are called with derived class object. On the other hand, if you simply declare `virtual` function in derived class but do not define it then it's a linker error. No segmentation fault.

> What should I do if I don't want to define all the functions in my
>   base class on my derived class but still have the necessary
>   inheritance in place?

Though this is unclear, I would say, you simply don't declare/define `virtual` function (which you don't want) in derived class. It will use base class `virtual` functions.

Comment: with regards to the last question you answered, if they are functions only to be executed internally then makeing them private will stop them from being inherited right?

Comment: @Flyphe, no. Access specifier cannot forbid a function being inherited (i.e. overridden). You can still override it. And internally if the function is called (with derived class object) then still it can resolve to the overridden function. [See the demo](http://www.ideone.com/3XmWL).

Comment: so private variables and functions CAN be inherited? then whats the point of having protected then?

Comment: @Flyphe: You are confused, I am afraid. A `Derived` class *IS* a `Base`, and adds some other things; therefore it has all the properties of a `Base`, comprising attributes and methods. However, if the method is `private`, then it cannot be called from a `Derived` method. The `virtual`-ness simply adds a quirk here, so that a `Derived` method (foo) can actually override a `private` `Base` method (foo). It cannot call the `private` `Base` method (foo) itself, just override it, but because it overrides it then any `Base` method can call it (foo) and get the new `Derived` behavior.

Comment: ohhh ok. yeh i was getting a little confused. thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

If you do not reimplement a `virtual` method, a caller will call the base class one. This is sort of the point of using inheritance, IMO.

If you do not want a base class to implement a virtual method, you can declare it like this:

```
class Demo {
    void foo() = 0;
};
```

This is what is called an abstract class. *Note that you cannot create an instance of such a class*. Any class which inherits from `Demo` must implement `foo()`, or it will also be an abstract class, and as such not instansiable.